# How to select multiple elements with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

My objective is making a function to toggle password visibility. The problem is that in the same Doc I have 3 different inputs that I also need the toggle visibility function, tho these inputs are not related to the password.

I tried with the name attribute, but it felt like over complicating, since I had names for each icon and input.I have no idea what to use to make the function, and I know there must be an easier way.

```
<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 50 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event handler on every `fa-eye` elements to toggle the opacity of its [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) element if it is an `input`.

And there would be nothing to change on your razor extention method call.

```js
$(".fa-eye").on("click", function(){
  let nextInput = $(this).next("input");
  let visibility = nextInput.css("opacity") == "1" ? 0 : 1;
  $(this).next("input").css("opacity", visibility)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
<input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="" /><br>

<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
<input id="Password2" name="Password2" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="" /><br>

<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
<input id="Password3" name="Password3" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="" /><br>
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm quite slow tonight... It took time before I figure out what you want even if it's obvious! Have a look now!

```js
$(".fa-eye").on("click", function(){
  let nextInput = $(this).next("input");
  let visibility = nextInput.attr("type") == "password" ? "text" : "password";
  nextInput.attr("type", visibility)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
<input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="Abc_123" /><br>

<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
<input id="Password2" name="Password2" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="My_Password" /><br>

<i class="float-right fa fa-eye fa-lg" id="toggleVisibility"></i>
<input id="Password3" name="Password3" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="Pr!vat3" /><br>
```

Comment: Thank you! just what I needed. Tho toggle just hides the input box :P.

Comment: Ho... And that defaces your layout? You would prefer to change the opacity?

Comment: Edited with a CSS opacity toggle...

Comment: Okay... Wires connected in my brain. I edited again.